# Windows CLI doesn't show correct variables with spaces

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, windows-10, mediainfo

There is this command line tool for [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en-us/MediaInfo/Download/Windows) that we use to print video file information. E.g. I want to get video file duration value:

```
mediainfo --Inform=General;%Duration/String2% video.mkv
46 min 57 s
```

As you can see it prints `46 min 57 s` which is correct.

Now lets say I want to put that value into a variable. So we run this:

```
for /f "usebackq" %a in (`"mediainfo --Inform=General;%%Duration/String2%% video.mkv"`) do set duration=%a
set duration=%46
```

As you can see it gives `set duration=%46` on a new line? And if I type next `%duration%` I get:

```
'%46' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What is going on? How do I get my `%duration%` variable show `46 min 57 s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackqDELIMS=" %%a
```

The default delimiters include space. This syntax disables delimiters so the entire line is assigned.

The `metavariable` a needs to have 2 `%` if you are running a batch file containintg this line. If you are running from the prompt, you need `%a`. This applies to the assignment instruction as well.

No idea what you are attempting to do with the `%46` malarkey. Please explain.

Comment: "usebackqDELIMS=" worked and prints correct values with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

**In a batch file:**

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('mediainfo --Inform=General;%Duration/String2% video.mkv') do set duration=%%a
echo %duration%
pause
```

**In CMD**

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('mediainfo --Inform=General;%Duration/String2% video.mkv') do set duration=%a
echo %duration%
```

**Output:**

> 46 min 57 s

Comment: In CMD it prints entire wall of text with all the information and value set to %duration% and echo %duration% gives "Forced: No" which was the last item in the printed list.